# How can i draw byte array on surfaceviewer in android?

Tags: android, surfaceview

I have got a video byte array format, how can i draw on surfaceViewer in android 2.2? i
 am trying  video chat. I m using onPreviewFrame and i have got a byte[] i will send to server and than  the server send to other client and the other client will has got a byte[], my problem is that: How   can i draw this(byte[]) on client ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is all codes for your app , I mean here is your `videochat` or part of this :) ,I didn't try my code on android 2.2, but it works for android 2.3.3 , it works like this , you are setting some device local ip address in `editText` and then you must push chat video button , so other part , whose ip address you set , will see video of your front camera

here is the java code

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.ImageFormat;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.YuvImage;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.ErrorCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.Size;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private ImageView m_VideCaptureBitmap;
    Camera mCamera;
    Button m_StartVideoChat;
    Button m_close_camera;
    EditText IPAdresse;
    private SurfaceView m_VideoCaptureView;
    private static final int TIMEOUT_MS = 10000;
    private static final int server_port = 13011;
    byte[] m_buffer ;

    @SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "NewApi", "NewApi" })
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
        m_VideoCaptureView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.imgSentView);

        m_close_camera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCameraClose);
        m_close_camera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCamera.release();              
            }
        });


        m_VideCaptureBitmap = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        IPAdresse = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etIPAdresse);
        IPAdresse.setText("192.168.2.32");
        m_StartVideoChat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartVideo);
        m_StartVideoChat.setOnClickListener(this);


        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                byte[] buffer = new byte [2048];
                DatagramSocket s;

                try {
                    s= new DatagramSocket(server_port);
                    s.setSoTimeout(TIMEOUT_MS);

                    while(true){
                        try {
                            final DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
                            s.receive(p);

                            m_buffer= buffer.clone();

                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    frameToBuffer(p.getData());
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        catch(Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (SocketException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    //rstep.setText("fail socket create");
                } 
            }

        }).start();
    } 

public void onClick(View arg0) {
    switch(arg0.getId()){
    case R.id.btnStartVideo:
            startVideo();

    }
}

private Camera openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread(Camera cam) 
{
    int cameraCount = 0;
    Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for ( int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++ ) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo( camIdx, cameraInfo );
        if ( cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT  ) {
            try {
                cam = Camera.open( camIdx );
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return cam;
}

private void startVideo() {
    if(mCamera != null) return;
    SurfaceHolder videoCaptureViewHolder = null;
    try {
        //openFrontFacingCameraGingerbread(mCamera);
        int camId = Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK;
        if (Camera.getNumberOfCameras() > 1 && camId < Camera.getNumberOfCameras() - 1) {
            int i = 1 + camId ;
            mCamera = Camera.open(i);
        }
        //mCamera = Camera.open();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        Log.e("CameraTest", "Camera Open filed");
        return;
    }
    mCamera.setErrorCallback(new ErrorCallback() {
        public void onError(int error, Camera camera) {
        }
    }); 
    Camera.Parameters parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPictureSize(10, 10);
    parameters.setPreviewFrameRate(5);

    List<Size> supportedPreviewSizes=parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    Iterator<Size> supportedPreviewSizesIterator=supportedPreviewSizes.iterator();
    while(supportedPreviewSizesIterator.hasNext()){
        Size tmpSize=supportedPreviewSizesIterator.next();
        Log.v("CameraTest","supportedPreviewSize.width = "+tmpSize.width+"supportedPreviewSize.height = "+tmpSize.height);
    }

    mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
    if (null != m_VideoCaptureView)
        videoCaptureViewHolder = m_VideoCaptureView.getHolder();
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(videoCaptureViewHolder);
    } catch (Throwable t) {
    }
    Log.v("CameraTest","Camera PreviewFrameRate = "+mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewFrameRate());
    Size previewSize=mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewSize();
    int dataBufferSize=(int)(previewSize.height*previewSize.width*
                           (ImageFormat.getBitsPerPixel(mCamera.getParameters().getPreviewFormat())/8.0));
    mCamera.addCallbackBuffer(new byte[dataBufferSize]);
    mCamera.setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer(new Camera.PreviewCallback() {

        private long timestamp=0;
        public synchronized void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

            int size = data.length;
            Size previewSize = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize(); 
            YuvImage yuvimage=new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, previewSize.width, previewSize.height, null);
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            //yuvimage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, previewSize.width, previewSize.height), 80, baos);
            yuvimage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, 128, 96), 80, baos);
            byte[] jdata = baos.toByteArray();
            int sizeOfData = jdata.length;

            DatagramSocket s;
            try {
                s = new DatagramSocket();
                s.setBroadcast(true);
                s.setSoTimeout(TIMEOUT_MS);
                InetAddress local = InetAddress.getByName(IPAdresse.getText().toString());

                DatagramPacket p = new DatagramPacket(jdata, jdata.length, local,server_port);
                s.send(p);

                }   catch (SocketException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            // Convert to Bitmap
            //Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(jdata, 0, jdata.length);
            //m_VideCaptureBitmap.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            //bitmapArray.add(bmp);


            // set our renderer to be the main renderer with
            // the current activity context

            //setContentView(glSurfaceView);



            Log.v("CameraTest","Frame size = "+ data.length);
            timestamp=System.currentTimeMillis();
            try{
                camera.addCallbackBuffer(data);
            }catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("CameraTest", "addCallbackBuffer error");
                return;
            }
            return;
        }
    });

    try {
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
        return;
    }
}


    private void frameToBuffer(byte[] data) {
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length);
        m_VideCaptureBitmap.setImageBitmap(bmp);        
    }
}
```

here is the xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">     

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etIPAdresse"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etTEXT"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Ip adress" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStartVideo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/etTEXT"
            android:layout_below="@+id/etTEXT"
            android:text="start video chat" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnCameraClose"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cancel camera" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/videoView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp" />

        <SurfaceView 
            android:id="@+id/imgSentView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

try it ;) , don't forget to upvote :) , and also don't forget to add these rows in manifest.xml

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Regards

Comment: can anyone do this without YuvImage, Jpeg, Bitmap? those conversions seem very heavy...